# Performance of threads and processes in linux

Tags: c++, linux

I have two scenarios in Linux that I've been working for some time in the same machine. The machine has two xeon processors each with 8 cores and 16 threads.

1. I have one code in c++ that is parallelized with openmp. In this scenario, if I use all threads (32 in total according to the Linux kernel) do I have any penalties in terms of concurrence between the threads ? I mean, setting 32 threads is the optimal configuration for this scenario ?
2. I run a given number of processes (all single threaded) using the same binary. Basically I have a script that spawn the same binary with different input files. In this scenario, what is the best way to launch these processes and not exhaust the machine ? I think that if I run 32 processes at the same time I will harm the performance of the machine.

Comment: Most of the time, you want to just let OpenMP decide how many threads to use on its own. Running 32 processes might or might not hurt performance--will typically depend on how I/O intensive they are. The mention of input files hints that they might be I/O bound, in which case you're rarely going to benefit from more than a few processes running concurrently (but it'll depend heavily on available bandwidth to storage).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The optimal one will generally be something between 16 and 32 for CPU-bound tasks ([hyperthreaded cores compete for the same resources](http://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=6&v=t)); for memory-bound or even IO-bound tasks it can be even lower.

   Still, in most cases using as many threads as cores can be a good starting point.
2. Why should it be harmful? In Linux, threads are just processes that happen to share the virtual address space (and most other OS resources). If you have enough RAM to keep them running without paging¹ and each process is single thread, 32 is as ok as per the thread case.

---

1. notice that the situation would be pretty much the same for an equivalent multithreaded program, as the program code is shared between the various instances of the application.

Comment: The processes uses the input once. The code reads the input and begins some intensive computations (quantum chemistry code). Some methods might use a lot of IO not all the time but in bursts. The use of memory is simple: the code allocates memory in the beginning with new and uses it until the end of the calculation. Physical ram available in the machine is enough for simultaneous calculation of 32 processes.